# Error C, implicit declaration function

Tags: c

Tengo la siguiente consigna : : Diseñar un programa que permita generar un archivo de texto que permita cargar cinco nombres separados por punto. Mostrar el contenido del archivo un nombre abajo del otro.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
int total;
char nombre[20];
char aux;
FILE *f;
f=fopen("4_1.txt","w");
if(f==NULL){
    printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo.\n");
    exit(1);
}
for(total=0;total<5;total++){
    printf("Ingrese el nombre numero %d:",total+1);
    fgets(nombre,20,stdin);
    fprintf(f,"%s.",nombre);
}
fclose(f);
f=fopen("4_1.txt","r");
if(f==NULL){
    printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo.\n");
    exit(1);
}
while(aux!=EOF){
    fgetc(f);
    if(aux=='.'){
        printf("\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("%c",aux);
    }
}
fclose(f);
printf("\n");
system("pause");
return 0;
```

El error que me aparece cuando trato de compilar es: 
En la linea donde esta exit (1), implicit declaration of function 'exit'[Wimplicit-fuction-declaratio]
Lo mismo me aparce con 'system'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Incluyes la cabecera que contiene esas funciones, en este caso `stdlib.h`
2. Haces las cosas bien.

Supongamos que optas por la segunda opción ¿A qué me refiero con hacer las cosas bien?

`exit()` sirve para finalizar la aplicación con un código de retorno... pero resulta que tu programa únicamente tiene una función `main()`. Al finalizar dicha función el programa termina.

En este caso, los usos de `exit()` se pueden sustituir sin problemas por un `return`.

Ejemplo:

```
// Cambia esto...
if(f==NULL){
    printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo.\n");
    exit(1);
}

// ... por esto
if(f==NULL){
    printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

¿Y qué pasa con `system`? Con `system` pasa que es un mecanismo muy lento y totalmente dependiente del sistema operativo... estás ejecutando comandos de consola con los que a duras penas puedes interactuar.

Conociendo los límites de C para gestionar la consola un buen sustituto podría ser:

```
puts("Pulse una tecla para continuar...");
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // limpiamos el buffer de entrada
getchar(); // Esperamos a que el usuario pulse una tecla.
```

Aunque en la mayoría de los casos se podría simplificar con:

```
puts("Pulse una tecla para continuar...");
getchar(); // Normalmente nos encontramos un salto de linea residual
getchar(); // Esperamos a que el usuario pulse una tecla.
```

Y con esto ya no necesitas hacer uso de la librería `stdlib`

Comment: Gracias por el consejo y la ayuda

Comment: Esta explicación es más completa que la mía @EmaB

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez aun así tu respuesta sigue siendo correcta... no veo motivo para no votarla

Answer (score 2):

Para que desaparezca ese error simplemente tienes que incluir la cabecera con el prototipo de esas funciones.

Los prototipos de las funciones `exit()` y `system()` se encuentran dentro del archivo `stdlib.h`. Al pertenecer a la librería estándar no hace falta que incluyas ninguna librería explícitamente al compilar. Sólo añade la siguiente línea al inicio:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono